# How I can write quotation marks correctly?

Tags: punctuation, quotchap

I have problen with quotation marks when I used in spanish language. This is an example a I got error 
*Package csquotes Error: ucs package not supported. \MakeOuterQuote{"}*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
    Carl Marx advirtió: "El Capital"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the x from utf8x.

Comment: But I want the text: Carl Marx advirtió: "El Capital" and removinx X from utx8 write different.

Comment: I see no difference, but in any case: remove the x, and if something is wrong then, ask a new question how to correct it.  csquotes won't work with utf8x/ucs.

Comment: The example works brilliantly for me if I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, just as Ulrike suggests. Normally `utf8` should be enough and `utf8x` should not be needed. And in fact `utf8x` sometimes creates more problems than it solves. Try without `x` and tell us what you don't like (with an example, the output you get, and the output you desired instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
``El Capital''
```

produces

[image]

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Change `utf8x` by `utf8` is a better solution than write ``El Capital'' because this produce `«El Capital»`that in Spanish is the recommended first level of quoting ([Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX).

Moreover, you yo not need `csquotes` for this, as `spanish` babel option provide the `<<` and `>>` shorthands to do the same.

Note that `<<...>>` is a  `quoting` environment, that unlike "..." and ``...'', it can be nested producing the right quotation marks: Spanish quillements in first level, English double quotation marks in the second, and single quotation marks in a third level, just as suggested by the RAE.

This is the same result that nesting three  times a `quoting` environment. or use the `\lquoti`, `\rquoti`, `\lquotii`, `\rquotii`, `\lquotiii` and `\rquotiii` marks

Instead, ``...'' as well as write directly the Spanish guillemets («...», in my Linux keyboard: `AltGr+Z` and `ALtGr+X`), are not environments, they  always produce the same marks, that cannot change according to the nesting level.

That you do not care of nested quotes? Ok, like me, but there are another good reason to use a true environment: You can redefine a environment to change the style of quoted text (change to italics, color, size...).

Other alternatives to <<...>> are   "`.... "' or  "< ...">  but the second cannot be nested. Note that moreover some babel shorthands are incompatible with some packages (for instance`csquotes`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Allowed quotes:}
Carl Marx advirtió: <<El Capital>>  (recommended) \par
Carl Marx advirtió: ``El Capital''  (allowed, but worse)\par
\subsubsection*{Nesting quotes: }
\begin{quoting}El 
\begin{quoting}gran 
\begin{quoting}Capital%
\end{quoting} de mi molsillo%
\end{quoting}\end{quoting}  (right way)\par
<<El ``gran `Capital' de mi bolsillo''>> (unnecesarily complicated)\par
<<El <<gran <<Capital>> de mi bolsillo>>>> (right easy way)\par
\end{document}
```